# Sim Card detection is not working in my iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

My code is:

```
if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [warningAlert show];
    return;
}
```

It works correctly with simulator but not working in iPhone without a SIM card.

Comment: Thanks mauris for editing.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code might be help you.

```
 CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier* carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;

    if(carrier.mobileNetworkCode == nil || [carrier.mobileNetworkCode isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        NSLog("Not available")
    }else{
        NSLog("available")     
    }
```

Comment: wellcome brother hppie coding